# Active PHP code using JavaScript and URL

Tags: javascript, php, url

I have a self destruct PHP code that would delete all files and folders in my domain's directory.

```
<?Php
    $dir = 'C:\wamp64\www\FileDirectory' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Files';
    $it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

    foreach($files as $file) {
        if ($file->isDir()){
            rmdir($file->getRealPath());
        } else {
            unlink($file->getRealPath());
        }
    }
    rmdir($dir);

    $filename = 'C:\wamp64\www\FileDirectory\Files';

    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        echo "The Directory has not been deleted";
    } else {
        echo "All Files And Folders Are Deleted";
    }
?>
```

I need a way to only activate this code when I type in extra code to the end of my URL. I thought you could do that with JavaScript but I'm not too certain. Please let me know if I can do this. If I have to use a different code to do so, it's not a big deal.

Comment: have you looked at `$_GET`-parameters? also: you should be extremely careful with that kind of code. *especially* when there is apparent lack in PHP-basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$_GET['parameter']` to get parameter from `get` method:

```
http://example.com/index.php?doClean=1

if (isset($_GET['doClean'])) {
    // Your code goes here
}
```